# Tensorflow model as service gives error

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask

I want to use a frozen pb model but have a problem like that:

ValueError: Fetch argument  cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Operation name: "init_1"
op: "NoOp"
 is not an element of this graph.)

```
import base64
import json, argparse, time
import sys
import tensorflow as tf

from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)

def load_graph(frozen_graph_filename):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(frozen_graph_filename, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="prefix")
    return graph


@app.route("/predict", methods=['GET'])
def predict():
    start = time.time()

    persistent_sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    image_b64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(open('1.jpg', "rb").read())
    y_out = persistent_sess.run(y, feed_dict={ x:image_b64 })

    return 'Success'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        port = int(sys.argv[1])
    except Exception as e:
        port = 80

    print('Loading the model')
    graph = load_graph('output/open_nsfw.pb')
    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/input:0')
    y = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prefix/predictions:0')

    persistent_sess = tf.Session(graph=graph)

    print('Starting the API')
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

Stacktrace:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
>         return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
>         response = self.handle_exception(e)
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
>         return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
>         reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
>         raise value
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
>         response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
>         rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function
>         return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
>         reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
>         raise value
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
>         rv = self.dispatch_request()
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
>         return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
>       File "/home/notebook/tensorflow-open_nsfw-master/tf.py", line 32, in predict
>         persistent_sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
>         run_metadata_ptr)
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 969, in _run
>         fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_string)
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 408, in __init__
>         self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 238, in for_fetch
>         return _ElementFetchMapper(fetches, contraction_fn)
>       File "/home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 274, in __init__
>         'Tensor. (%s)' % (fetch, str(e)))
>     ValueError: Fetch argument  cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Operation name: "init_5"
>     op: "NoOp"
>      is not an element of this graph.)

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace. Where does the error occur?

Comment: I add full stacktrace

Comment: Does loading and using the model work without Flask? Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for that scenario?